# Java irc bot ping pong

Tags: java, bots, irc

```
if (serverResponse.contains("PING ")) {
    writer.write("PONG " + serverResponse.substring(5) + "\r\n");
    writer.write("PRIVMSG " + c.getHomechannel() + " :I got pinged!\r\n");
    System.out.println("pinged");
    writer.flush( );
}
```

and

```
if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("PING")) {
    TCPRequestManager.sendWrite("PONG " + param);
    TCPRequestManager.doMsg("c.getHomechannel()", ":I got pinged!");
    TCPConnectionManager.getWriter().flush( );
}
```

both SEEM to work and send me the message saying the clients been pinged but i don't think its actually returning the pong due to disconnecting, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the [PONG message contain a destination](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-3.7.3)? I'm guessing the `serverResponse.substring(5)` in the first code block is the servername of the server *pinging* your server. It's expecting a PONG *from* your server *to* the irc server.

Typically, the transaction looks something like this, **a.com** is the hostname of the irc server, **b.com** is the hostname of the bot connected to it:

```
PING :a.com          (sent from a.com to b.com)
PONG b.com :a.com    (sent from b.com to a.com)
```

It looks like what you're sending (given the previous example) is:

```
PING :a.com          (sent from a.com to b.com)
PONG :a.com          (sent from b.com to a.com, except there's no origin)
```